# Following the new WhatsApp data privacy update, why does WhatsApp ask from users, even if they didn't, who is going to check their source code?

Tags: privacy, account-security, facebook, whatsapp

New ***WhatsApp** data privacy update*, that it will share our data with **Facebook**, we all know Facebook owns WhatsApp and this is obvious Facebook can always access users of WhatsApp as well. So why to ask from us even if they can do it and we won't even complaint against it?
And what if Facebook access WhatsApp users data, who is responsible to check source code of these apps?

Comment: "Why don't they just access data?" Privacy regulations. "But we won't complain!" Irrelevant to regulations. And I'm not sure how source code review factors into anything. Can you explain or rephrase that part of the question?

Answer (score 0):

As Schroeder stated, it is not a matter of them just "accessing the data". Sure, Facebook owns WhatsApp but that doesn't mean they can outright skirt the law. Even though there is nothing *technically* stopping them. The law & the impending huge fine is a deterrent of this behaviour, as it is designed to be.

If Facebook were to access WhatsApp data without informing users in their privacy policy that this takes place, that is a huge infringement of privacy regulations.